# Regex – re.sub explanation

Tags: python, regex

I understand that the function of re.sub is to substitute A with a B, however, here I don't understand the manipulation done when () are modified in the string greay, and I don't get the role of `\g<1>` `\g<2>` etc.

[image]

Comment: Didn't the tutorial explain it before the exercises?

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a regex, parenthesis are a capture group. This means that you want to save one particular part of a match, and use it later. `\g<1>` is a way of saying "the first capture group", `\g<2>` is a way of saying "the second capture group", and so on.

`re.sub()` behaves interestingly. The first string is the things to look for, and the second string is what to replace it with. If you leave the second string empty, it just deletes whatever the match is; if you add some text, it'll replace all the matches with that text. But what if you want to take the text you matched and add it back in? That's where `\g<#>` comes in handy! Using it, you can put that same string you matched right back where you found it.

- `(gr[ae]y)` means "if you find `grey` or `gray`, delete it like normal, but also remember it." The replacement string `\g<1>blue` means "take the first match that we remembered, `"grey"`; add that text, and then put `blue` after it". Thus, `greyblue` is the result, since it deleted `grey` like normal, but then inserted it back in before `blue`.
- `()gr[ae]y` means "if you find `grey` or `gray`, delete it like normal, but remember the empty string right in front of it." The replacement string `\g<1>blue` means "take the first match that we remembered, `""`; add that text, and then put `blue` after it". Thus, `blue` is the result, since it deleted `grey` like normal, and inserted an empty string before `blue`.

[See a more in-depth explanation here, with your examples and more!](https://repl.it/repls/ImaginarySparseDigits)